# Android JNI - Google console backtrace crash not correct

Tags: android, java-native-interface, backtrace

I have app in Google Play. It uses JNI native library. On my test devices all is running fine, however, in Google play console, I can see this for many users `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)`:

```
backtrace:

  #00  pc 00000000001f5072  /data/app/com.example.myapp-1==/lib/arm/libutils.so (_ZNK6Octree7GetNodeEv+7)

  #01  pc 00000000001d6eb7  /data/app/com.example.myapp-1==/lib/arm/libutils.so (_ZNK5Utils11GetActiveIDEv+10)

  #02  pc 00000000001b1fe9  /data/app/com.example.myapp-1==/lib/arm/libutils.so (CUtilsGetActiveID+4)

  #03  pc 0000000000128913  /data/app/com.example.myapp-1==/lib/arm/libutils.so (Java_com_example_myapp_UtilsAPI_getGroupInfoText+366)

  #04  pc 0000000000168953  /data/app/com.example.myapp-1==/oat/arm/base.odex
```

However, in `Utils::GetActiveID` there is no call to `Octree::GetNode`. Why is it shown in backtrace? I am not sure how to found the problem if the crash log backtrace is incorrect.

Comment: Perhaps the heap has become corrupted, due to e.g. a use-after-free.

Comment: @Michael and how to debug this or found?

Comment: You could try using AddressSanitizer or Valgrind. It might not be of much use if you can't reproduce the problem though.